# Data load in Snowflake: NULL result in a non-nullable column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

I am getting the error message: NULL result in a non-nullable column on my loading my parquet files into Snowflake.

I have NOT null columns in Snowflake for example, NAME2, NAME3, but the values against them in the parquet files are empty string.

So my question is how can I resolve this constraint without changing my table definition or without removing not null constraint?

```
COPY INTO "DB_STAGE"."SCH_ABC_INIT"."T_TAB" FROM (
SELECT
$1:OPSYS::VARCHAR,
$1:MANDT::VARCHAR,
$1:LIFNR::VARCHAR,
$1:LAND1::VARCHAR,
$1:NAME1::VARCHAR,
$1:NAME2::VARCHAR,
$1:NAME3::VARCHAR,
$1:NAME4::VARCHAR,
..
..
$1:OPTYPE::VARCHAR
FROM @DB_STAGE.SCH_ABC_INIT.initial_load_stage_ABC)
file_format = (type = 'parquet', NULL_IF=('NULL','',' ','NULL','NULL','//N'))
pattern = '.*/ABC-TAB-prod/.*snappy.parquet';
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what `SELECT $1` looks like?  It might help to identify why a blank value is being evaluated as a NULL.

Comment: SELECT
$1
FROM @DB_STAGE.SCH_P2R_INIT.initial_load_stage_P2r


returns:

Invalid UTF8 detected in string 'PAR10xFC0xE00x020x48spark_schema0xBE0x00%OPSYS%0x000x00%MANDT%0x000x00%BUKRS%0x000x00%BELNR%0x000x00%GJAHR%0x000x00%' File 'output_partition/SXSLTP08-BSEG-prod/part-00000-027b3451-acce-4c87-93e1-19ba00642ee2-c000.snappy.parquet', line 1, character 1 Row 1, column "TRANSIENT_STAGE_TABLE"["$1":1]

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this line

```
file_format = (type = 'parquet', NULL_IF=('NULL','',' ','NULL','NULL','//N'))
```

is explicitly asking to take the empty strings and make them into NULL values, which obviously won't work going into fields that are NOT NULL in your table.  You should probably try something like this:

```
file_format = (type = 'parquet', NULL_IF=('NULL','//N'))
```

Your other option is to remove the NOT NULL in your table and allow the conversion to NULL.

Comment: file_format = (type = 'parquet', NULL_IF=('NULL','//N'))  did not work. Still gives me the same error: NULL result in a non-nullable column

Answer (score 3):

Looking at these options there is some guidance on NULLs particularly for parquet

NULL_IF = ( 'string1' [ , 'string2' , ... ] )
Use
Data loading only

Definition
String used to convert to and from SQL NULL. Snowflake replaces these strings in the data load source with SQL NULL. To specify more than one string, enclose the list of strings in parentheses and use commas to separate each value.

This file format option is applied to the following actions only when loading Parquet data into separate columns using the MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME copy option.

Note that Snowflake converts all instances of the value to NULL, regardless of the data type. For example, if 2 is specified as a value, all instances of 2 as either a string or number are converted.

For example:

NULL_IF = ('\N', 'NULL', 'NUL', '')

Note that this option can include empty strings.

Default
\N (i.e. NULL, which assumes the ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD value is \)

from the docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

There's also more content I found under communities: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009Vw7ktSAB/how-can-i-get-schema-file-when-copy-into-file-returns-empty-row

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008UE4MKSA1/while-loading-a-parquet-file-to-snowflake-all-the-optional-field-in-parquet-schema-are-coming-as-null-any-idea-why-it-is-happening-all-other-fields-which-are-mandatory-in-parquet-schema-as-coming-as-expected

Let me know if these help

Answer (score 1):

Try switching `empty_field_as_null=false` in `file_format`.

Comment: empty_field_as_null=false, where would it fit in the script?

Comment: file_format = (type = 'parquet', NULL_IF=('NULL','',' ','NULL','NULL','//N'), empty_field_as_null=FALSE)

Comment: gives me error: SQL compilation error: Option EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL is not valid for file format type parquet.